# Error installing sqlite

Tags: installation

When I tried to install `sqlite3` using the command `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`, I got the error

```
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird_14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type this

```
 sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/thunderbird_14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
```